# Why does $AB = 2R\sin{\frac{AB}{2}}$?

Tags: geometry

I was reading my problem book and one of the solutions to a problem said

> The length of a chord $AB$ of a circle with radius $R$ is equal to $2R\sin{\dfrac{AB}{2}}$.

They said this "is readily discerned from the equilateral triangle $AOB$, where $O$ is the center of the circle."

This doesn't make sense to me since this seems to assume that $R = AB$. Am I misunderstanding what they are saying?

For more context, this quote came from a solution to a problem about a point on the circumscribed circle of a regular $n$-sided polygon and proving that the sum of the squares of the distances from this point to all the vertices is equal to $2nR^2$.

[image]

Comment: What is $\frac{AB}2$ in $\sin\frac{AB}2$ ? Does $AB$ here mean $\angle AOB$ ?

Comment: This is terrible notation. $AB$ is the length of a chord, not an angle you divide by 2 and take the sine of. Moreover, the triangle mentioned is not equilateral but isosceles. Just draw radii to the edges of the chord, call the central angle $\theta$, and use the law of sines.

Comment: @symplectomorphic Is what they are saying right?

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the derivation. Did you mean

$$ 2R\sin{\dfrac{AB}{2R}} ?$$

A crude skecth is given. So, author's shorthand for " angle subtended by chord $AB$ at center $O$ = 2 u" is simply $AB\,!$. At some places an arc or roof symbol is given overhead to denote angle.

[image: CentralAngle]

Comment: Please see added picture.

Comment: If that's the case then how do we know that the angles are equal to the arc lengths? So actually I think they do mean side length here then.

Answer (score 0):

$\qquad\qquad\quad$[image]

Consider the triangle $\Delta OAB$ with $\angle AOB=\theta$ and the radius of the circle with centre $O$ as $R$. Using the law of sines, we have,

$$\frac{AB}{\sin\angle AOB}=\frac{AO}{\sin\angle ABO}=\frac{BO}{\sin\angle OAB}$$

Now, we have $AO=BO=R$, the radius of the circle. So, $\Delta AOB$ is an isosceles triangle (the equal sides being $AO$ and $BO$) which implies that $\angle OAB=\angle OBA=\dfrac{\pi-\theta}2$ (sum of angles in a triangle add up to $\pi$).

So, we have,

$$\frac{AB}{\sin\theta}=\frac{R}{\sin(\frac 12(\pi-\theta))}\implies AB=\frac{R\sin\theta}{\sin(\pi/2-\theta/2)}=\frac{R\sin\theta}{\cos(\theta/2)}$$

Using the double-angle formula for sine, i.e., $\sin\theta=2\sin(\theta/2)\cos(\theta/2)$ we have,

$$AB=2R\sin(\theta/2)=2R\sin\dfrac{\angle AOB}2$$

which seems to be what you want.

Comment: There is no need for this since we can just say $AB = 2R\sin{\dfrac{\angle{AOB}}{2}}$ by a right triangle.

Comment: Angular measure is equal to arc length measure if and only if the circumference of the circle is unity.

Comment: @Puzzled417, The thing is, in the formula your text states, it seems that the author is using $AB$ inside the sine function as a shorthand for $\angle AOB$ instead of the arclength $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$. For the above diagram in my answer, using Geogebra, I'm getting negative value for the side length of $AB$ if I consider the $AB$ inside the sine function to denote the arc-length. Basically, the problem is the terrible notation in your text, nothing more.

Comment: If you look at the later part of the solution they use the assumption that $AB$ is the side length. But they get the right conclusion so is it still wrong?